# .NET Core - BLAZOR - Custom component - Store async Task in dictionary for later usage with EventCallback

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I have a built a custom Blazor component which have a dictionary with parameters.

It is a common component and is in located in the main layout `<SharedComponent></SharedComponent>`.

The component renders another component inside of and passes parameters via the dictionary - in below line of code the dic is `parameters`.
The following code renders the child component.

```
ComponentService.Add<ChildComponent>(text, parameters, taskParameters);
```

PS: There are two dictionaries: - one for ordinary parameters; - one for functions.

---

How I think this should be achieved:

1. Store the async Task into a dictionary with `Func` delegate.
2. Retrieve it later and assign it to multicast delegate.
3. Create new EventCallback and passing the delegate to it.
4. Invoke the callback event passing the return item.

**My question:**

**Is this the correct way at all or there is some other approach?**

---

What I have tried so far and I need some help with it...

Here is the dictionary:

```
public class ComponentTaskParameters
{
    private Dictionary<string, Func<Task>> taskPparameters;

    public ComponentTaskParameters()
    {
        taskPparameters = new Dictionary<string, Func<Task>>();
    }

    public void Add(string parameterName, Func<Task> value)
    {
        taskPparameters[parameterName] = value;
    }

    public Func<Task<T>> Get<T>(string parameterName)
    {
        if (!taskPparameters.ContainsKey(parameterName))
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException($"{parameterName} does not exist in component parameters");
        }

        return (Func<Task<T>>)taskPparameters[parameterName];
    }
}
```

---

Let's say that this is the async function:

```
async Task SaveItem(Item item)
{
    // save code
}
```

I tried to store it into the dictionary both wit `Func` and `Action` but no luck.

How I can do this and is it achievable at all?

---

I created a delegate

```
delegate Item SaveItemDelegate(Func<Task, Item> saveTask);
```

I am not able to add the retrieved function from the dictionary to the the delegate.

Here is how I create the `EventCallback`

```
var callbackEvent = new EventCallback<Item>(null, saveItemDelegate);
```

And I am not able to invoke the callback with `CallbackEvent.InvokeAsync(Item);`.

Appreciate all the help here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to store the SaveItem function as multicast delegate in the dictionary.

```
// Insert into dict function
public void Add(string parameterName, MulticastDelegate value)
{
    taskPparameters[parameterName] = value;
}

// Declaration of the delegate
public delegate Task SaveDelegate(Item item);

// New delegate
SaveDelegate saveDelegate = new SaveDelegate(SaveItem);

// Store the delegate in the dictionary
taskParameters.Add("CallbackFunction", saveDelegate);
```

Then I was able to retrieve it and pass it to the `EventCallback`. Then to invoke it successfully.

```
// Pull out from the dict function
public MulticastDelegate Get(string parameterName)
{       
    return taskPparameters[parameterName];
}

// The delegate
MulticastDelegate save = TaskParameters.Get("CallbackFunction");

// Create new 'EventCallback'
EventCallback callback = new EventCallback(null, save);

// Invoke the 'EventCallback'
callback.InvokeAsync(item);
```